# how to run sh file in linux command line

Tags: python, linux, shell, revitpythonshell

```
//init.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PATH="${HOME}/.pyenv/scripts:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

pyenv shell ammt-crawler
```

I want to run init.sh file in linux command line 
And make sure pyenv shell ammt-crawler line is executed.

but When I just put ./init.sh nothing happend. 
is there why to execute the init.sh file in linux?

(ps) if you can please explain to me what export , eval mean inside of this init.sh

Comment: the shell bang line `#!/usr/bin/env bash
` must be first line of the script file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add execute permissions to the script :

```
chmod +x unit.sh
```

and try running it again.

Answer (score 1):

Comments in `bash` start with `#`, not `//`. Also, the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`) must be on the first line of the file to have any effect. So the script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# init.sh

export PATH="${HOME}/.pyenv/scripts:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

pyenv shell ammt-crawler
```

Also, if you want to be able to execute it with just `./init.sh`, it needs to be executable. Run this command to make it executable:

```
chmod +x init.sh
```